# Default root folder not working after renaming wwwroot Web API .NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core web api application. I renamed wwwroot folder to clientapp and build use that folder as the output folder for an angular application.
So whenever I use
ng build
it outputs the compiled files the clientapp folder of my Web Api project.
Everything working fine till this level

So in the Program.cs file I did this change to use default directory

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .UseWebRoot("clientapp");
                });
```

and in startup.cs

```
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

and in launchsettings.json

```
  "launchUrl": "index.html",
```

But when I execute the application it shows page cannot be displayed, but the url shows

```
https://localhost:44331/index.html
```

**But it was working fine till I renaming wwwroot folder**

What I did wrong or did I miss something??

Answer (score 1):

I have got a solution which is am not 100% sure its the best/correct way. But it made the application starts working.

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"clientapp"))
        });
```